# If $u_n \geq 0$ quasieverywhere, is also $u \geq 0$ quasieverywhere?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, potential-theory

Let $u_n \to u$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ on abounded domain, where eg. $p=2$.

If $u_n \geq 0$ quasieverywhere, is also $u \geq 0$ quasieverywhere?

Would weak convergence be sufficient for the limit to be non-negative too?

Quasieverywhere means it holds on all $x \in \Omega$ except on a set of capacity zero.

Comment: If you only have the regularities $u_n, u \in L^p(\Omega)$, then it does not make sense to speak about quasi-everywhere, since you can change $u$ on arbitrary sets of measure zero and these sets may have positive capacity.

Comment: Sorry @gerw. I mean $W^{1,p}$ for $p$ sufficiently large.

Comment: What does it mean "quasieverywhere"? I can't find the definition

Comment: @SeñorBilly It is written in my post!!!

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to ask what does it mean "capacity zero". I initially thought it's the same as "measure zero", but apparently not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, since $u_n \to u$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$
implies that there is a subsequence $u_{n_k}$ such that $u_{n_k}(x) \to u(x)$ for quasi-every $x \in \Omega$. Now, you first assertion follows easily.

*Edit:* It is also possible to consider the following: you can easily show $u(x) \ge 0$ for almost all $x \in \Omega$. Since $u$ is quasi-continuous, this implies $u(x) \ge 0$ for quasi-all $x \in \Omega$.

In the case of weak convergence, you can apply Mazur's lemma and get that a sequence of convex combinations of $u_n$ converges strongly to $u$. Together with the first assertion, this yields the claim.